# MySql create new table with columns from an existing table and distinct lookup from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 existing tables on a database namely `Table_1` and `Table_2`.

I need to combine the info of `Table_1` and `Table_2` into a new table named `Combined_table`.

The `Table_1` columns names and values can be directly copied into `Combined_table`.

I then need to add columns with names consist on the distinct values from `Service Description` in `Table_2`. Each distinct value must become a column name added to the `Combined_table`.

These new added columns must then have their respective values added to the correct row. Each row can be identified via the `MSISDN` column available in all tables.

`Table_1`

```
|MSISDN        |Abar Date  |Upgrd |Pack Code |Tariff               |Avg Spend |SIM Number
|--------------|-----------|------|----------|---------------------|----------|---------------------|
|9602005689344 |18-Mar-15  |Y     |MDA       |Machine2Machine Data |32.56     |89490000000000001215 |
|9602005926494 |06-Feb-15  |Y     |MLT       |Machine2Machine Lite |27.38     |89490000000000004457 |
|9602005926509 |06-Feb-15  |Y     |MLT       |Machine2Machine Lite |10.1      |89490000000000045677 |
|9602005926524 |06-Feb-15  |Y     |MLT       |Machine2Machine Lite |31.77     |89490000000000002887 |
|9602005926539 |18-Mar-15  |Y     |MDA       |Machine2Machine Data |32.36     |94900000000000100212 |
|9602006330948 |11-Mar-16  |N     |MLT       |Machine2Machine Lite |4.39      |89460000000015600111 |
|9602006330950 |11-Mar-16  |N     |MLT       |Machine2Machine Lite |4.39      |89940000000000426577 |
|--------------|-----------|------|----------|---------------------|----------|---------------------|
```

`Table_2`

```
|MSISDN         |Service Description               |Value     |
|---------------|----------------------------------|----------|
|9602005689344  |100MB                             |25.44     |
|9602005689344  |Basic Data 9600                   |0.00      |
|9602005689344  |Basic Telephony                   |6.58      |
|9602005689344  |Ebilling - Corporate CD Extract   |0.00      |
|9602005689344  |Unrestricted APN                  |0.00      |
|9602005926494  |100MB                             |25.44     |
|9602005926494  |Basic Data 9600                   |0.00      |
|9602005926494  |Basic Telephony                   |4.39      |
|9602005926494  |Ebilling - Corporate CD Extract   |0.00      |
|9602005926494  |Unrestricted APN                  |0.00      |
|9602005926509  |Basic Data 9600                   |0.00      |
|9602005926509  |Basic Telephony                   |4.39      |
|9602005926509  |Ebilling - Corporate CD Extract   |0.00      |
|9602005926509  |My Meg 0                          |0.00      |
|9602005926509  |Unrestricted APN                  |0.00      |
|9602005926524  |100MB                             |25.44     |
|9602005926524  |Basic Data 9600                   |0.00      |
|9602005926524  |Basic Telephony                   |4.39      |
|9602005926524  |Ebilling - Corporate CD Extract   |0.00      |
|9602005926524  |Unrestricted APN                  |0.00      |
|9602005926539  |100MB                             |25.44     |
|9602005926539  |Basic Data 9600                   |0.00      |
|9602005926539  |Basic Telephony                   |6.58      |
|9602005926539  |Ebilling - Corporate CD Extract   |0.00      |
|9602005926539  |Unrestricted APN                  |0.00      |
|9602006330948  |Basic Data 9600                   |0.00      |
|9602006330948  |Basic Telephony                   |4.39      |
|9602006330948  |Caller Identity FREE              |0.00      |
|9602006330948  |Ebilling - Corporate CD Extract   |0.00      |
|9602006330948  |My Meg 0                          |0.00      |
|9602006330948  |Promotional My Gig 1 - 24 Months  |0.00      |
|9602006330948  |SMS Mobile Originating            |0.00      |
|9602006330948  |Unrestricted APN                  |0.00      |
|9602006330950  |Basic Data 9600                   |0.00      |
|9602006330950  |Basic Telephony                   |4.39      |
|9602006330950  |Caller Identity FREE              |0.00      |
|9602006330950  |Ebilling - Corporate CD Extract   |0.00      |
|9602006330950  |My Meg 0                          |0.00      |
|9602006330950  |Promotional My Gig 1 - 24 Months  |0.00      |
|9602006330950  |SMS Mobile Originating            |0.00      |
|9602006330950  |Unrestricted APN                  |0.00      |
|---------------|----------------------------------|----------|
```

Example of how the `Combined_table` should look like.

```
|MSISDN         |Abar Date  |Upgrd  |Pack   |Code Tariff            |Avg Spend  |SIM Number             |100MB  |Basic Data 9600    |Basic Telephony    |Caller Identity FREE   |Ebilling - Corporate CD Extract    |My Meg 0   |Promotional My Gig 1 - 24 Months   |SMS Mobile Originating |Unrestricted APN   |
|9602005689344  |18-Mar-15  |Y      |MDA    |Machine2Machine Data   |32.56      |89490000000000001215   |25.44  |0.00               |6.58               |0.00                   |0.00                               |0.00       |0.00                               |0.00                   |0.00               |
|9602005926494  |06-Feb-15  |Y      |MLT    |Machine2Machine Lite   |27.38      |89490000000000004457   |25.44  |0.00               |4.39               |0.00                   |0.00                               |0.00       |0.00                               |0.00                   |0.00               |
|9602005926509  |06-Feb-15  |Y      |MLT    |Machine2Machine Lite   |10.10      |89490000000000045677   |0.00   |0.00               |4.39               |0.00                   |0.00                               |0.00       |0.00                               |0.00                   |0.00               |
|9602005926524  |06-Feb-15  |Y      |MLT    |Machine2Machine Lite   |31.77      |89490000000000002887   |25.44  |0.00               |4.39               |0.00                   |0.00                               |0.00       |0.00                               |0.00                   |0.00               |
|9602005926539  |18-Mar-15  |Y      |MDA    |Machine2Machine Data   |32.36      |89490000000000100212   |25.44  |0.00               |6.58               |0.00                   |0.00                               |0.00       |0.00                               |0.00                   |0.00               |
|9602006330948  |11-Mar-16  |N      |MLT    |Machine2Machine Lite   |4.39       |89460000000015600111   |0.00   |0.00               |4.39               |0.00                   |0.00                               |0.00       |0.00                               |0.00                   |0.00               |
|9602006330950  |11-Mar-16  |N      |MLT    |Machine2Machine Lite   |4.39       |89940000000000426577   |0.00   |0.00               |4.39               |0.00                   |0.00                               |0.00       |0.00                               |0.00                   |0.00               |
```

I have no idea how to create the table using PHP. 
I thought about executing a single MySQL request to create and add the data, but dont know how to start.

Any advice will be very helpful.

Comment: If this is a MySQL question, why did you tag it with Microsoft's "SQL Server" too?  Tag one or the other. Don't tag both.

Comment: Copying data like this into a second table is generally a bad idea. It is probably a much better approach to create a view that combines the data the way it want. That way there is only copy of the data and you never have to worry about keeping all the tables in synch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the column names (i.e. distinct descriptions) already then you can create a table and write a `SELECT` query like this:

```
SELECT MSISDN, Abar Date, Upgrd, Pack Code, Tariff, Avg Spend, SIM Number,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(VALUE), 0) FROM Table_2 WHERE MSISDN = t1.MSISDN AND description = '100MB') AS 100MB,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(VALUE), 0) FROM Table_2 WHERE MSISDN = t1.MSISDN AND description = 'Basic Data 9600') AS 'Basic Data 9600',
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(VALUE), 0) FROM Table_2 WHERE MSISDN = t1.MSISDN AND description = 'Basic Telephony') AS 'Basic Telephony',
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(VALUE), 0) FROM Table_2 WHERE MSISDN = t1.MSISDN AND description = 'Ebilling - Corporate CD Extract') AS 'Ebilling - Corporate CD Extract',
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(VALUE), 0) FROM Table_2 WHERE MSISDN = t1.MSISDN AND description = 'Unrestricted APN') AS 'Unrestricted APN'
FROM Table_1 t1;
```

You can create a table with these columns and use INSERT INTO .. SELECT syntax, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO table_3
SELECT MSISDN, Abar Date, Upgrd, Pack Code, Tariff, Avg Spend, SIM Number,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(VALUE), 0) FROM Table_2 WHERE MSISDN = t1.MSISDN AND description = '100MB') AS 100MB,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(VALUE), 0) FROM Table_2 WHERE MSISDN = t1.MSISDN AND description = 'Basic Data 9600') AS 'Basic Data 9600',
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(VALUE), 0) FROM Table_2 WHERE MSISDN = t1.MSISDN AND description = 'Basic Telephony') AS 'Basic Telephony',
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(VALUE), 0) FROM Table_2 WHERE MSISDN = t1.MSISDN AND description = 'Ebilling - Corporate CD Extract') AS 'Ebilling - Corporate CD Extract',
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(VALUE), 0) FROM Table_2 WHERE MSISDN = t1.MSISDN AND description = 'Unrestricted APN') AS 'Unrestricted APN'
FROM Table_1 t1;
```

Comment: Appreciate Darshan. Kindly see my follow up comments below.

Comment: @LouisMeyer I have added `COALESCE` in the query, try now?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Darshan

I managed to compile the following using your sugestions and some real life data from the live database tables.

Create the temp table which works fine:

```
CREATE table `infolog_SIMS` (`MSISDN` VARCHAR(50), `Abar Date` VARCHAR(50), `Term Date` VARCHAR(50), `Upgrd` VARCHAR(50), `Upgrd date` VARCHAR(50), `Pack Code` VARCHAR(50), `Tariff` VARCHAR(50), `Pack Desc` VARCHAR(50), `Avg Spend` VARCHAR(50), `Stat` VARCHAR(50), `SIM Number` VARCHAR(50));
```

Then add extra columns the the temp table, also works fine::

```
ALTER TABLE `infolog_SIMS` ADD COLUMN `100MB` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `Basic Data 9600` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `Basic Telephony` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `Ebilling Corporate CD Extract` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `LTE` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `MMS Standard` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `Unrestricted APN` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `My Meg 0` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `SMS Mobile Originating` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `Caller Identity FREE` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `Promotional My Gig 1 24 Months` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `MyMeg 30 Mobile Internet Bundle` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `15MB` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `SPNwww.infolog.co.za` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `Make Nat. Int. Roam Calls` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ADD COLUMN `Outgoing Bar` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
```

Now to add the  for each rows with values:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = '100MB') AS '100MB', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'Basic Data 9600') AS 'Basic Data 9600', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'Basic Telephony') AS 'Basic Telephony', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'Ebilling Corporate CD Extract') AS 'Ebilling Corporate CD Extract', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'LTE') AS 'LTE', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'MMS Standard') AS 'MMS Standard', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'Unrestricted APN') AS 'Unrestricted APN', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'My Meg 0') AS 'My Meg 0', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'SMS Mobile Originating') AS 'SMS Mobile Originating', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'Caller Identity FREE') AS 'Caller Identity FREE', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'Promotional My Gig 1 24 Months') AS 'Promotional My Gig 1 24 Months', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'MyMeg 30 Mobile Internet Bundle') AS 'MyMeg 30 Mobile Internet Bundle', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = '15MB') AS '15MB', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'SPNwww.infolog.co.za') AS 'SPNwww.infolog.co.za', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'Make Nat. Int. Roam Calls') AS 'Make Nat. Int. Roam Calls', (SELECT `Value` FROM `Infolog_temp_VAS` WHERE `Dialling No` = `t1`.`MSISDN` AND `Service Description` = 'Outgoing Bar') AS 'Outgoing Bar' FROM `Infolog_temp_SDR` `t1`;
```

Some of the `Value` fields returns `NULL` if the service does not exist in the `Infolog_temp_VAS` table. Will it be possible to add an `IF` condition in case the `service` does not exist in order to change the `NULL` to `NO` instead?

Note this is not the actual insert command but the select portion only.